# Cannot cast Application to Class

Tags: java, android

i have the following class:

```
    public class Mediator extends Application
{
    private HTTPSender sender;

    public Mediator()
    {
        sender = new HTTPSender();
    }

    public void sendMessage()
    {

    }
}
```

Now in my activity i do the following:

```
public class Contact extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Mediator mediator;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.mediator = (Mediator) getApplication();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

When i run my application i get the following:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to dk.AnApp.app.Mediator
```

Can anyone tell me why i am unable to cast it to a class that extends application?

Comment: Why do you think that putting HTTP logic in a custom `Application` subclass is sensible?

Comment: @CommonsWare not sure what your are asking but im using the Mediator design pattern to control the folow of my application (between the logic and then activities)

Comment: And what makes you think that a custom `Application` is a sensible `Mediator`?

Comment: @CommonsWare - Well, it allows them to ensure a single instance of their Mediator object (if the application is open, then there is a single application object instance) without resorting to constants (or large amounts of static methods). And conceptually it makes sense for the application itself to mediate it's behavior. I too am curious, is there some specific objection you have to the idea? Or perhaps a reason that it would not be good practice?

Comment: @RudiKershaw: "it allows them to ensure a single instance of their Mediator object" -- even if a singleton `Mediator` were a good idea, it would be far more flexible to use an actual singleton (Java static data member). Even better would be to use an event bus, or possibly RxJava, rather than burying business logic in some singleton, begging for memory leaks and spaghetti code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your manifest you should declare that `Mediator` is the `application` class so it gets instantiated as the application.

For example,

```
<application
    android:name="dk.AnApp.app.Mediator"
    ...
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm)

This takes care of the exception but does not guarantee that your `Mediator` class exists for a good reason (as CommonsWare points out in comments).

Answer (score 2):

```
this.mediator = (Mediator) getApplication();
```

I think that this is your issue. `getApplication()` is returning an `Application` which is a super class of `Mediator` and so you can not cast down the inheritance tree like this.

```
<application 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:name="ThisApplicationClass" // Here
    >
```

Adding a `android:name` attribute into your application element in your manifest file (as above) can get the Android API to return the correct class type for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have performed:

```
this.mediator = (Mediator)getApplication()
```

and it worked!
I did have my Manifest ok, also extends Application in the other class. But I still had this cast issue.
Fortunately, I could resolve it! :D
Thanks!